# What should be the "minimal representation of the app" in Redux?

Tags: redux

I know the answer to this question might be obvious. But, I still want to have a clear answer.

In Redux, it says: "The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within a single store".

Let's say we have the following data:

According to the Redux doc, all the data of "todos" should be placed in the store. In the section "Designing state shape", it also says "the minimal representation" of the app.

```
{
  todos: [
    {id: 1, description: "Seal the wall"}
    {id: 2, description: "Wash the car"}
  ]
}
```

If there are only two operations on "todos" like "Add" and "Delete", should the redux store only keep the following data?

```
{
  todos: [1, 2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Operations(Actions) that you perform on your state are completely separate from the state store. The store does not and should not care about what actions are going to happen on it.

So no, the store should not be:

```
{
  todos: [1, 2]
}
```

and should be:

```
{
  todos: [
    {id: 1, description: "Seal the wall"}
    {id: 2, description: "Wash the car"}
  ]
}
```